# JRuby JDBC-mysql error

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jruby

I have JRuby + Swing application and want to add `jdbc/mysql` there

```
require "jdbc/mysql"
```

But when I'm trying to run it, I have the followig error:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- jdbc/mysql
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1033
   (root) at olap_frontend.rb:3
```

My gem list:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.2.2)
activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter (1.2.2)
bouncy-castle-java (1.5.0146.1)
bundler (1.1.3 ruby)
jdbc-mysql (5.1.13)
jruby-launcher (1.0.12 java)
jruby-openssl (0.7.6.1)
rake (0.9.2, 0.8.7)
rubygems-bundler (0.3.0 ruby)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try require "active_record" instead

Comment: LoadError: no such file to load -- active_record
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1033
   (root) at olap_frontend.rb:4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault - I need to require `rubygems` first

Comment: If anyone happens across this when using Ruby 1.9, this is only an issue in 1.8. 1.9 requires rubygems automatically.